# Can a process call "down" on two semaphores at once?

Tags: c, kernel, semaphore

Let's say *two* semaphores are protecting a critical piece of code, and you only want a critical piece of code to execute if both of them are available. Is there a pattern for writing this?

In other words, is there a statement that reads, "If semaphore a and b are available, then run... otherwise sleep"?

Comment: While I don't think it's possible, a trick for this is to always acquire the resources (call `down`) in the same order in all of your code. If you are consistent about it, the availability of A will imply the availability of B. You can also try making A higher priority and have any code which has B and cannot `down` A, `up` B. Why would you have two semaphores protecting one piece of code?

Comment: What thread library are we talking about here?

Comment: What you need it's known as multiple semaphore and it could be implemented using actually another semaphore and variables. Are you using `pthread`?

Comment: It's a problem about an agent putting down two out of three keys on the table. There are three threads, each with one of the keys. The thread with the key that completes the set can unlock and perform an action. So instead of trying to use semaphores only, I'm combining a single semaphore with an array of condition variables. @pat this is basic kernel C without any additional libraries.

Comment: When does "basic kernel C" mean?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to implement this is to use a single `pthread_mutex_t` to protect some state, and a single `pthread_cond_t` to notify all threads when the state has changed.  If you always broadcast on the condvar, then you will always wake all waiting threads.  The threads can then perform arbitrarily complex tests and updates to the shared state.

Of course, this is not the most efficient solution since it potentially wakes threads when the state does not satisfy the condition they are waiting for (and they have to go back to sleep).  It could also lead to starvation since a thread may always find itself at the back of the queue whenever it waits on the condvar, and never find an acceptable state when it awakens.

Without knowing more details of the problem you are trying to solve, it is hard to give an air tight answer.

`pthreads` does not allow you to acquire multiple locks/semaphores atomically; however, as pointed out by @Greg, you can avoid deadlock by assigning an order to the locks/semaphores, and having the threads always acquire them in that order.  Of course, you have to know which locks you intend to acquire before you start to acquire any of them.  It will not work if you cannot determine the next lock to acquire until you have acquired the current one, since you may be required to take a lock out of order.  If you release all of the locks and start over, you may find the state has changed, requiring you to acquire a different set of locks, which could lead to livelock.